# Getting image from custom field not default header image (featured image)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How would it be possible to revise the following script, so that an image from a created custom field is displayed, rather than from the default header image (which is set by a featured image)? Could I do something like this and make it work: ($post->ID, 'header-image', true)?

I've tried to setup a custom field called ***header-image*** but would like guidance on how to properly script it.

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) :
    $featuredimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'resonar-large' );
?>
<div class="entry-header-background" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $featuredimage[0]
```

**ATTEMPTED REVISION**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
 <?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) :
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post_id, 'header-image', true);
?>
<div class="entry-header-background" style="">
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><img  src="http://www.example.com/images/<?php echo get_post_meta($post- >ID, 'header-image', true); ?>" alt="Icon for Post #<?php the_ID(); ?>" /></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) functio to retrieve the value stored in the custom field.

```
$custom_field = get_post_meta($post_id, 'header-image', true);
?>
<div class="entry-header-background" style="background-image:url(<?php echo esc_url( $custom_field [0]
```

Comment: Hi @Hareesh Sivasubramanian. Thanks for your kind reply. Could you please take a look at what I tried to attempt, posted in my original post? I can see the pathway to the image works in the rendered html but it doesn't actually show the image.

Comment: Can you post the link to your website, if it is live?

Comment: Stupidly, as sometimes it inevitably happens, I set the div to display: none; on a previous test (!). Thank you so much for the help and support!